# Using ctags to find variables declared with a constructor in c++

Tags: c++, linux, vim, ctags

By using this command

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=l -x test.cpp
```

ctags can only find variable c2 and not varibale c3

code snippet :

```
int main()
{
  int c2 = 5;
  int c3(3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this looks like something that would be difficult for ctags to parse. My advice: find a tag generator that uses  llvm to statically analyze the source. If you're curious about why this is difficult to parse, see this article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 2):

Universal-ctags(https://ctags.io/) can capture c3.

```
[jet@localhost ctags]$ cat /tmp/foo.cpp
int main()
{
  int c2 = 5;
  int c3(3);
  return 0;
}
[jet@localhost ctags]$ ./ctags --kinds-C++=+l -o - /tmp/foo.cpp
c2  /tmp/foo.cpp    /^  int c2 = 5;$/;" l   function:main   typeref:typename:int    file:
c3  /tmp/foo.cpp    /^  int c3(3);$/;"  l   function:main   typeref:typename:int    file:
main    /tmp/foo.cpp    /^int main()$/;"    f   typeref:typename:int
```